# HTML Symbols are being displayed as a question mark in SQL Server Database

Tags: html, sql-server, symbols

Today i noticed that html symbols such as: ★ are being displayed in my database as a question mark.

I'm using varchar as type and the database i am using is microsoft sql 2008.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `NVARCHAR` datatype for your column, VARCHAR datatype can only be use for non-unicode character.

if you are storing unicode characters in your datatype you should use NVARCHAR datatypes and when inserting Data into your Column use the `N` prefix telling sql server there will be some unicode characters in the passed string.

**With VARCHAR DataType**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (Column1 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('★')
SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

**Result**

```
╔═════════╗
║ Column1 ║
╠═════════╣
║ ?       ║
╚═════════╝
```

**With NVARCHAR DataType**

```
CREATE TABLE  #Tempn (Column1 NVARCHAR(100) )
INSERT INTO #Tempn VALUES(N'★')        --<-- N prefix for Unicode Characters
SELECT * FROM #Tempn
```

**Result**

```
╔═════════╗
║ Column1 ║
╠═════════╣
║ ★       ║
╚═════════╝
```

Comment: Nice answer, and if I'm passing a parameter can I just put N@test, will work?

Comment: I want to do something like the following:

DECLARE @test NVARCHAR = 'N"★ "'
create table test (abc nvarchar)
insert into test values (@test)
 select * from test

the code above is just an example, I will pass value to the parameter from .NET, How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Define the symbol as an NVARCHAR instead of a VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tablename values (N'★ ')
```

above is the syntax for inserting and make sure your field data type is `nvarchar` or try this test example

```
create table test (abc nvarchar)
insert into test values (N'★ ')
 select * from test
```