# java hibernate mysql "&nbsp;"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm using hibernate and mysql.
When persist string html in specific string `"&nbsp;"`. In the database is showed `"?&nbsp;"`.
I don't know how this "?" character going to database

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859787/html-symbols-are-being-displayed-as-a-question-mark-in-sql-server-database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to look at tips on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A good question improve your chances of getting an answer. Most importantly, before posting a question make sure you have done some searching and research - this helps members of the community to know what you have already looked at.